# SQL IN operator in update query causes a lot of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Below is a update query which is to update a table with about 40000 records:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET colA = val, colB = val
WHERE ID IN (select RecordIDs from tableB where needUpdate = 'Y')
```

When the above query is executed, I found out that the below query taken ~ 15 seconds

```
SELECT RecordIDs
FROM tableB
WHERE needUpdate = 'Y'
```

But when I take away the where clause (i.e. `update tableName set colA = val, colB = val`) The query runs smoothly.

Why this happens? are there any ways to shorten the time of execution?

---

Edited:

Below is the structure of both tables:

```
tableName:
    ID int,
    VehicleBrandID int,
    VehicleLicenseExpiryDate nvarchar(25),
    LicensePlateNo nvarchar(MAX),
    ContactPerson nvarchar(MAX),
    ContactPersonID nvarchar(MAX),
    ContactPersonPhoneNumber nvarchar(MAX), 
    ContactPersonAddress nvarchar(MAX),
    CreatedDate nvarchar(MAX),
    CreatedBy nvarchar(MAX)
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)



  tableB:
    RowNumber int
    RecordIDs int
    NeedUpdate char(1)
    PRIMARY KEY (RowNumber)
```

---

Edited

Below screenshot is the execution plan for the update query

[image]

Comment: Provide schemas for both tables. How many (in percentage) rows are selected from both tables for this query to execute?

Comment: So all rows in `tableB` have `needUpdate = 'Y'` and they match all rows in `tableName`? And still provide schemas for both.

Comment: Yes, Please wait for my edit, I'm updating the table schemas

Comment: Which database software and version is this? (SQL Server?)

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2012

Comment: `MERGE` is *generally* a faster option than this or `UPDATE FROM`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: @Nicarus: "MERGE is generally a faster option" --- curious, any explanation of that?

Comment: @zerkms I've updated, tableB just provide a list of RecordIDs that need to update the values

Comment: What are the indexes on tableB?

Comment: Check the execution plan that, where query is slowing down. I believe you don't have created any index or PK in tableB

Comment: @Harsh Baid I've double checked the two tables, the two tables have primary key, please see my edit.

Comment: @SQLhint.com Just now edited table B, the primary key is RowNumber

Comment: @User2012384: are you updating the PK? Anyway, you should move the clustered index to another column, or make your PK as non-clustered.

Comment: @SQLhint.com I am not updating the PK, how can I make a primary key non-clustered?

Comment: By default a PK is marked as clustered, that's why I (wrongly) supposed you're performing an update on PK. The idea is you're performing an UPDATE on a clustered index, and this is a time consuming operation. Check if your business rules allows you to move the clustered index on other column (or even on PK).

Comment: @SQLhint.com I've removed the Primary key from the table.

Comment: @User2012384 - **Don't**. That is a complete red herring. The reason why the plan shows a CI update is because the clustered index leaf pages *is* the table so of course it needs to be updated.

Comment: You should leave the PK on `ID` and consider adding another index on the second variable. `DECLARE @tenancyEditable TABLE (RowNumber int  PRIMARY KEY,RecordIDs int,NeedUpdate char(1),UNIQUE (NeedUpdate, RecordIDs, RowNumber))` and try with and without the `RECOMPILE` hint.

Comment: What's the use of "UNIQUE"?

Comment: @User2012384 - In versions of SQL Server prior to 2014 the only way of adding indexes to table variables is via unique or primary key constraints.

Comment: I'll give it a try~Please wait for my result..

Comment: check the link [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/why-is-it-doing-a-clustered-index-update.13598/) if it helps you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution plan shows you are using table variables and are missing a useful index.

Keep the existing PK on `@output`

```
DECLARE @output TABLE (
  ID                       INT PRIMARY KEY,
  VehicleBrandID           INT,
  VehicleLicenseExpiryDate NVARCHAR(25),
  LicensePlateNo           NVARCHAR(MAX),
  ContactPerson            NVARCHAR(MAX),
  ContactPersonID          NVARCHAR(MAX),
  ContactPersonPhoneNumber NVARCHAR(MAX),
  ContactPersonAddress     NVARCHAR(MAX),
  CreatedDate              NVARCHAR(MAX), /*<-- Don't store dates as strings*/
  CreatedBy                NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

And add a *new* index to `@tenancyEditable`

```
DECLARE @tenancyEditable TABLE (
  RowNumber  INT PRIMARY KEY,
  RecordIDs  INT,
  NeedUpdate CHAR(1),
  UNIQUE (NeedUpdate, RecordIDs, RowNumber))
```

With these indexes in place the following query

```
UPDATE @output
SET    LicensePlateNo = ''
WHERE  ID IN (SELECT RecordIDs
              FROM   @tenancyEditable
              WHERE  NeedUpdate = 'Y')
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Can generate the more efficient looking

[image]

Also you should use appropriate datatypes rather than storing everything as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. A person name isn't going to need more than `nvarchar(100)` at most and `CreatedDate` should be stored as `date[time2]` for example.

Comment: Just now added a clustered index to the table, and the speed increases a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are in one of the 2 cases below:

1/ [STATISTICS are not updated](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/when-update-statistics-flag-2371) due to a some recently modification of in your table. In this case you should execute this:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS tableB
```

2/ I suppose [a wrong query plan is used](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/sqlserver/how-to/ho-avoid-delete-or-invalidate-query-plan), case when I recommend to execute this in order to force recompilation of the query:

```
SELECT RecordIDs
FROM tableB
WHERE needUpdate = 'Y'
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Tell us the result and we'll come with more details about.

Comment: All rows are selected for `tableB`, so no indexes will be used anyway.

Comment: @zerkms: it can use an index in case a bad query plan is cached.

Comment: oh, it actually makes sense!

Comment: Please see my edited execution plan, the query executed much faster than before, and the SQL server took about 1.5 sec to recompile

Comment: @User2012384: It is still too much. Does it execute faster when you're not using OPTION(RECOMPILE)?

Comment: yes the query does execute faster than before, but how long should it take to compile a query?

Comment: @User2012384 - The reason `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` helps is probably because it assumes the table variable will only emit one row. Using this option allows it to take account of the actual number of rows and thus it may well choose something other than nested loops. 1.5 seconds to recompile such a simple query sounds very odd though. Are you sure?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Why are you saying "the table variable will only emit one row?". Please detail.

Comment: @SQLhint.com - The statement will be compiled before the table variable has any rows inserted (when it is empty) and the plan will show a table cardinality of 0. It still estimates one row will be emitted from a query against an empty table though [as described here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10220/3690). If the statement is recompiled after the rows are inserted it can take account of the number of rows the TV contains. Though there are no more granular column statistics on these.

Comment: [More info about table variables here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/3690)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks for the link, I still get it, where do you see a table variable in the query? Or you mean the subquery (after IN operator) behaves like a table variable?

Comment: @SQLhint.com - Both tables involved are table variables going off the names shown in the graphical plan. (`@output` and `@tenancyEditable`). The single row assumption also explains why it would have a scan on the inside of the nested loops. Though the thickness of the arrows shows this assumption is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can use inner join instead of IN clause.

```
 update  t
 set
t.colA = val, t.colB = val
From tablename 
inner join tableb x on
t.id = x.recordid 
where x.needUpdate = 'Y'
```

Although the `UPDATE...FROM`
syntax is essential in some
circumstances, I prefer to use
subqueries (by using IN clause) whenever
possible.

Comment: "you can use inner join instead of IN clause." --- sql server would optimize them in a similar way

Comment: Just now tested the query using inner join but the execution time is still the same...

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative. It is worth it to try in your environment as it has been demonstrated for others to be faster.

```
   MERGE INTO tableName tn
       USING (
              SELECT recordIDs
                FROM tableB
               WHERE needUpdate = 'Y'
             ) tb
          ON tn.ID = tb.recordID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE 
          SET colA = tb.val, 
              colB = tb.val;
```

EDIT:
I am not claiming this to be faster in every case or in every setup/environment - just that it is worth a try as it has worked for me and others I have worked with or read about.

Comment: Not to argue it cannot be faster but "as it has been demonstrated" --- does it have a technical explanation?

Comment: @zerkms Sure and fair question. My own experience is one component, but there are some benchmarks and tests available for review (one example: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2651/comparing-performance-for-the-merge-statement-to-select-insert-update-or-delete/) It is important to state that some benchmarks include both insert/update vs just update comparisons.

Comment: execution plans would be 100 times more informative. PS: the article is a bit irrelevant - it's about more sophisticated scenarios, not trivial like here

Comment: @zerkms I agree - I don't have that luxury right at this moment. Not sure the harm in testing it on one's own.

Comment: actually it's expected to be faster for upsert operations, but it surprises me it should be better than a trivial update

Comment: @zerkms If you would like to test it on your own, I would highly encourage that. I simply am offering as an alternative to try and I've very clearly stated that in my answer. I'm not in the position to dissect or reverse engineer this at the moment. Just trying to offer a suggestion.

Comment: Hi Nicarus, Thanks for your suggestion Just put the query but found out that it's a bit slower (~10sec slower) than using in operator and using inner join..

Comment: @User2012384: not surprising for such a trivial case actually :-)

Comment: @zerkms One should not so quickly dismiss the value of testing/trying something different - it's good to test things even if you aren't certain it is the solution. Breaks one away from ignorance and even arrogance.